# Debug Rcpp with ldbb: variables not available

Tags: rcpp, lldb, rcpparmadillo

I'm making **a package with RcppArmadillo** under the latest version of Rstudio (1.3.959) and R (4.0.0).

Consider the following minimal example, which create the package **anRpackage**:

```
library(Rcpp)
library(RcppArmadillo)
RcppArmadillo.package.skeleton()
```

Setting the working directory in this package, I load it by:

```
library(devtools)
devtools::load_all()
```

Then the basic function rcpparma_hello_world() can be executed:

```
rcpparma_hello_world()
```

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    7    0    0
[2,]    0    7    0
[3,]    0    0    7
```

- I want now to [debug the code with lldb](https://kevinushey.github.io/blog/2015/04/13/debugging-with-lldb/) *via* the Terminal command `R -d lldb` in order to check the variable values during the execution *via* the command `frame variable`.

```
R -d lldb
(lldb) breakpoint set --name rcpparma_hello_world()
(lldb) run
> library(devtools)
> devtools::load_all()
> rcpparma_hello_world()
```

```
anRpackage.so was compiled with optimization - stepping may behave oddly; variables may not be available.
```

Indeed, the problem is that **most of variables are not available**:

```
> next
> frame variable
```

```
(arma::mat) m1 = <no location, value may have been optimized out>
(arma::mat) m2 = <no location, value may have been optimized out>
```

- I read in the previous link the following recommandations:

> you may consider producing so-called ‘debug’ builds, with optimization toned down, when attempting to debug these kinds of issues as well. For building R packages, this effectively amounts to something like `CXXFLAGS=-g -O0` in your `~/.R/Makevars` file)

- I have tried it but it seems to have **no effect under the compilation flags used** since I have a local file **Makevars** in my package to specify the way of [compiling with RcppArdimillo](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/blog/2017/06/04/), whose flags are:

```
CXX_STD = CXX11
PKG_CXXFLAGS = $(SHLIB_OPENMP_CXXFLAGS) 
PKG_LIBS = $(SHLIB_OPENMP_CXXFLAGS) $(LAPACK_LIBS) $(BLAS_LIBS) $(FLIBS)
```

Then, the command `devtools::load_all()` produces the line-command compilation given below, in which there is indeed `-g -O2` making some code optimization:

```
clang++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -std=gnu++11 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/Rcpp/include' -I'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/RcppArmadillo/include' -I/usr/local/include    -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c rcpparma_hello_world.cpp -o rcpparma_hello_world.o
```

**Question**: how can I have access to the variables in *debugging* mode?

Thanks

Comment: You probably need help from `r-sig-mac` for this.

Comment: I just need to send an email to the following list: r-sig-mac@r-project.org, right? 
No idea about making the optimization toned down in SHLIB_OPENMP_CXXFLAGS ?
Thank you @DirkEddelbuettel

Comment: Yes, and all (well, most, possibly all) emails list at the R Project now require _initial signup first_ to reduce spam a little.

Comment: Thanks, I sent an email. Also I have edited the previous post by providing a **minimal example** with a debug of `rcpparma_hello_world()`.

Comment: The [solution](https://gist.github.com/alexg9010/1ab89ecb28c43f8bc217d2facca77f0a) was to specify in `~/.R/Makevars` the flag `ALL_CXXFLAGS= -Wall -g -O0 $(LTO)` (and not only `CXXFLAGS=-g -O0`)